# Java2D Graphics Spec: Rasterization

Tags: java, opengl, graphics2d

This is **not** about "How do I use Java Graphics 2D?"

My question is: "What is the mathematical specification for Graphics2D? What is the specification that determines how strokes, fonts, and shapes, and rasterized into pixels?"

For example, suppose I wanted to implement an OpenGL backend for Java Graphics2D, what would I need to know about the spec on how strokes/fonts/shapes are rasterized, in order to have it render to OpenGL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never come across a mathematical spec. I believe the rasterization is generally regarded as an implementation specific detail as Java can make use of DirectX or OpenGL capabilities provided by the host system.

Here's some good reading, if you haven't already found them:

- [Rendering with Java 2D](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/2d/spec/j2d-awt.html#wp67506)
- [System Properties for Java 2DTM Technology](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/2d/flags.html)
- [Diagnosing Rendering and Performance Issues](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/tsg/TSG-Desktop/html/java2d.html#gdpio)